# c# how to generate all combinations of a word by using char arrays for each position in a word

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dictionary, console

Hi I would like to generate a word dictionary of a word and then based on arrays that represents possible chars that could make up the position in that word.I need to have all possible uppercase and lowercase combinations of the letters and also substitute certain letters with the symbols 0,@ and 5
what I mean is :

Say the word is "*support*" 
I need to generate a dictionary with all possible combinations for example:
*5uPport , SupP0rt or SUPP0RT* ...

I thought about using multiple arrays that represents each letter for example:

```
char[] s = {s,S,5};
char[] u = {U,u};
```

then i have strings to represent the positions in the word support that I would join after some `loops` which creates the word, however I don't know how this would look. Is there a better way to do this and can some one show me an example of code please.

Comment: Question: Why do you need this dictionary? Sure I can write you a few lines of code to fill this dictionary, but my guess is you later want to use this dictionary for matching text - in which case regular expressions might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(
    string s,
    Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<char>> substitutions)
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(
        string original, 
        string current, 
        int index)
    {
        if (index == original.Length)
        {
            yield return current;
        }
        else
        {
            if (substitutions.TryGetValue(
                original[index],
                out var chars))
            {
                foreach (var c in chars)
                {
                    foreach (var combination in
                        GetCombinations(original,
                                        current + c,
                                        index + 1))
                    {
                        yield return combination;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return Enumerable.Repeat(s, 1);

    var lowerCased = s.ToLower();
    return GetCombinations(lowerCased,
                           string.Empty,
                           0);
}
```

And you'd call it previously building your substitution dictionary:

```
var substitutions = new Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<char>>();
substitutions.Add('s', new[] { 's', 'S', '5' });
substitutions.Add('o', new[] { 'o', 'O', '0' });
substitutions.Add('p', new[] { 'p','P' });
substitutions.Add('u', new[] { 'u', 'U' });
substitutions.Add('r', new[] { 'r', 'R' });
substitutions.Add('t', new[] { 't', 'T' });
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    GetCombinations("support", substitutions)));
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm going to test this out!

Comment: @ITplease you need to read on two subjects, you’ll find plenty of information in SO or simply googling: recursion and iterators.